# Slice to the end of a string without using len()

Tags: python, string, slice

With string indices, is there a way to slice to end of string without using `len()`?

Negative indices start from the end, but `[-1]` omits the final character.

```
word = "Help"
word[1:-1]  # But I want to grab up to end of string!
word[1:len(word)]  # Works but is there anything better?
```

Comment: This is covered in the Python tutorial and in SO's own [standard answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) for slice questions.

Comment: OK feel free to delete if it's spam!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can instead try using:

```
word[1:]
```

Answer (score 26):

Or even:

```
>>> word = "Help"
>>> word[-3:]
'elp'
```

Answer (score 15):

I found myself needing to specify the end index as an input variable in a function.  In that case, you can make `end=None`.  For example:

```
def slice(val,start=1,stop=None)
    return val[start:stop]

word = "Help"
slice(word)  # output: 'elp'
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for when I came here. I imagine it is relevant to many other people as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course, you should:

```
word[1:]
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for this?

```
>>> word = "Help"
>>> word[1:]
'elp'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always just do it like this if you want to only omit the first character of your string:

```
word[1:]
```

Here you are specifying that you want the characters from index 1, which is the second character of your string, till the last index at the end. This means you only slice the character at the first index of the string, in this case 'H'.
Printing this would result in: 'elp'

Not sure if that's what you were after though.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is useful to save the index, for example to use it on other variables or to pass it to functions. Here, `slice` objects come in useful.

```
>>> word = "Help"
>>> index = slice(1,None) # equivalent to [1:] indexing
>>> word[index]
'elp'
>>> sentence = "Help with Python indexing."
>>> sentence[index]
'elp with Python indexing.'
```

Answer (score -3):

```
word="Help" 
word[:]
```

> 'Help'

I hope this helps you